# Why is colorpicker width never applied in css?

Tags: javascript, css, game-development

```js
var colorScript = document.createElement('script')
colorScript.src = "example.com/script.js"
var input = document.createElement('input')
input.className = "jscolor {onFineChange:'panel.style.background = this.toHEXString();'}"
input.id = "panelColor";
input.value = '000000';
document.head.appendChild(colorScript)
document.head.appendChild(input)
```

```css
#panelColor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 35px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

Why is the colorpicker width never applied in css? I have to manually set it using the css property in js.

Comment: Your JS code doesn't include any width set

Comment: yes, it will work if i apply it in JS, i dont know why it won't set in CSS.

Comment: you set in css `panelTitleColor` and I cant see any `panelTitleColor` id  in html

Comment: its changed to the correct id, still not altering the width

Answer (score 0):

Your width is determined by `left` and `right` property.
In your case its 10px from the left of the div and 35px from the right of your div.

So your width is the full width of your div minus 10 minus 35.

In your case, you should use the `width` property as percentage, not in fixed pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You set id as `panelColor` in js and in css you  use `#panelTitleColor`

So set in css `#panelColor`

```
#panelColor{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: i have that exact setup, but looking in the  elements tab, i see the property 'width' has a line through it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
input.id = "panelColor";
```

You can use this and check you css

```
 input.setAttribute("id", "panelColor");

#panelColor{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 60px;
}
```